# Load ESRI Vector Tiles in mapbox-gl

Tags: vector, tiles, esri, mapbox-gl

I am using mapbox-gl v 1.8.0. I am trying to load ESRI Vector Tiles using the ArcGIS Online service. Here is my code snippet

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = '<your access token here>';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container id
style: 'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/OpenStreetMap_GCS_v2/VectorTileServer/resources/styles/root.json', // stylesheet location
center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
zoom: 9 // starting zoom
});
```

Do I need to create an access token to access that style in ArcGIS Online?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: That is a public service, you should not need a token

Comment: Did you find a solution to your question by any chance? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a very late replay, but yes, you can load Esri Vector tile basemap layers and other layers with MapBox. And yes, you need to sign up for a free account to get an access token.

```js
      const apiKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
      const basemapEnum = "ArcGIS:Streets";

      const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: "map", // the id of the div element
        style: `https://basemaps-api.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/styles/${basemapEnum}?type=style&token=${apiKey}`,
        zoom: 12, // starting zoom
        center: [-118.805, 34.027] // starting location [longitude, latitude]
      });
```

Go [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/mapbox-gl-js/maps/display-a-map/) for the full code